# Why is carbon monoxide the second-most common molecule in the interstellar medium?

Tags: astrophysics

I read this assertion in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_monoxide) under the astrophysics sub-section. Even though the carbon-oxygen triple bond in CO is the [strongest chemical bond](http://www.wiredchemist.com/chemistry/data/bond_energies_lengths.html) known with a bond-dissociation energy of 1072 kJ/mol, it is unstable according to the [Boudouard Reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boudouard_reaction) in an oxygen starved environment.

2CO ⇌ CO<sub>2</sub> + C

It is more unstable in an oxygen rich environment.

2CO + O<sub>2</sub>  =>  2CO<sub>2</sub> + energy

Both of the above reactions are exothermic.  In fact, the forward Boudouard reaction is exothermic at all temperatures but the reverse reaction takes place at temperatures above 975<sup>o</sup> K. This is because the reverse reaction is exergonic above this temperature even though the forward reaction is exothermic.

Molecule formation would be [restricted to the coldest regions](http://www.astronomynotes.com/ismnotes/s3.htm) of the interstellar medium where average temperature is around 10<sup>o</sup> K. This is because high energy photons in warmer regions would disassociate the atoms from the molecules.  The forward Boudouard reaction is exergonic at 10<sup>o</sup> K, albeit at a very low reaction rate.  It seems to me that enough time has elapsed in 13.7 billion years for the forward Boudouard reaction to convert most of the CO to 2CO<sub>2</sub>.

How is CO the 2nd most common molecule in the interstellar medium after H<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: Where is the 'carbon-hydrogen triple bond in CO'? And, in the interstellar medium with very low density how do you see the reaction of CO with O2 proceeding?

Comment: Meant carbon-oxygen. My bad.  Rather than the oxygen combustion reaction, the CO should degrade into CO2 and C due to forward  Boudouard.